# google map implemenyation java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

i keep on geting this exeption

```
05-31 07:42:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(4133): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-31 07:42:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(4133): Process: com.start.littldeamone, PID: 4133
05-31 07:42:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(4133): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start  activity ComponentInfo{com.start.littldeamone/com.start.littldeamone.MainActivity}:   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
05-31 07:42:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-31 07:42:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-31 07:42:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-31 07:42:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-31 07:42:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-31 07:42:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-31 07:42:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-31 07:42:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-31 07:42:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-31 07:42:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-31 07:42:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-31 07:42:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-31 07:42:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(4133): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
05-31 07:42:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
05-31 07:42:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
05-31 07:42:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
05-31 07:42:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
05-31 07:42:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
05-31 07:42:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
05-31 07:42:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at com.start.littldeamone.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:10)
05-31 07:42:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-31 07:42:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-31 07:42:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
05-31 07:42:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     ... 11 more
05-31 07:42:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(4133): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment that is not a Fragment
05-31 07:42:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:585)
05-31 07:42:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:561)
05-31 07:42:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4778)
05-31 07:42:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
05-31 07:42:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     ... 20 more
05-31 07:42:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(4133): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
05-31 07:42:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(4133):     ... 24 more
```

i have gone trought all stack overflow solotion and diddnt found the problem
chaing from mapactivity to frgment activity and so on... nothing has worked
this is my code
mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

activity main xml

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.start.littldeamone"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="AIzaSyA58hdExVacurnuB235ojNOJVsF6dH8MMg"/>
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
 Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.start.littldeamone.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

please help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First correct this you need to move both `<meta-data>` tag under `<application>` tag in your `manifest.xml` like.

```
<application>
<activity....>
......
 ....... 
<meta-data
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<meta-data
 android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
 android:value="AIzaSyA58hdExVacurnuB235ojNOJVsF6dH8MMg"/>

</application>
```

also here your **minsdk="8"** so you need to change this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
```

to

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

also your logcat clearly said

```
05-31 07:42:01.640: E/AndroidRuntime(4133): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment that is not a Fragment
```

That means you need to used

```
<fragment
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

For more information go to [Getting Started Google Maps API V2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2)